# HomeKit accessoryDidUpdateReachability not working

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

does anyone has a working implementation with accessoryDidUpdateReachability unter iOS8 / XCode 6.3?

playing around with HomeKit shows me very unstable change state of accessory reachability.

Status mostly only changes after restarting the app.

Comment: What kind of accessory are you communicating with (BLE or IP)?

Answer (score 2):

Reachability appears to be mostly broken in iOS 8.x. You can stimulate it by attempting to read, but I think that's frowned upon by apple. Even when reads report some value, the reachability value doesn't appear to update.

The good news is that it seems to work much better in iOS 9.

Comment: Thanks. I did a workaround with a 1s timer and checking the status for each device. HomeKit feels like early alpha status. Not what i was expecting from apple...

Comment: This seems to be completely broken in iOS 11, at least in my testing. When you switch or turn off Wi-Fi, it's `isReachable` remains true, and `accessoryDidUpdateReachability` is never called.

Comment: Still broken in iOS 14.7.1. accessoryDidUpdateReachability is never called!